# How to calculate probability of a binary function in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, binary, probability

Let us consider the following function:

```
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,&  \Pr(f(x)=0)=x \\  
 1,&  \Pr(f(x)=1)=1-x\end{cases}$,

where $0< x< 1$
```

**Trial:**
I have tried with the following code but I,m not sure whether it is correct or not. The codes are here:

```
import random
def f(x):
    b=random.randint(0,1)
    return b

x=0.3
count0=0
count1=0
for i in range(1000):
    if f(x)==0:
        count0=count0+1
    else:
        count1=count1+1
print 'pr(f(x)=0)=', count0*1.0/1000
print 'pr(f(x)=1)=', count1*1.0/1000
```

Does my code give the correct calculation? Please help?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Would the typesetted math look like [this](//i.imgur.com/zmKZMsw.png)? So `0` with a probability of `x`, otherwise `1`?

Comment: What is equivalent Python code for the defined function? @EmmanuelMtali

Comment: @Artyer yes, you are right.

Comment: Are you asking whether the result of f(x) is 0 with probability x, and otherwise 1? If you can't tell from looking at the code, you can try printing f(0) a few times, and see if it always produces 1, or printing f(1) a few times and see if it always produces 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say "0 with the probability of `x`, and 1 with the probability of `1 - x`", [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) returns a random number from `[0, 1)`, so you just check if `x` is greater than that number:

```
import random

def f(x):
    return x >= random.random()
```

Currently, your function returns `0` and `1` with a 50/50 chance.

Comment: I have used random.randint(0,1) which returns $0$ or $1$ randomly @Artyer

Comment: @MKS with an even probability of either `0` or `1`. This function takes into account `x`.

Comment: It seems that my python code does not give the correct probability according to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code does the correct solution (based on the binomial distribution you've created calling **N** times *f(x)* ).

However, the probability of selecting 0 or 1 randomly from (0, 1) is 50/50, but,  as you surely have noticed already, you're computing the probability for a given sample (Ex. [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]), not for the whole universe of calling infinite times f(x).

See: [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

You could write a more readable code if you store the results of the function in a list like this:

```
intents = []
num_intents = 1000

for i in range(num_intents):
    intent.append(f(x))
```

Then:

```
print('pr(f(x)=0)={}'.format(intents.count(0)/num_intents)
print('pr(f(x)=1)={}'.format(intents.count(1)/num_intents)
```

I also recommend you to explore [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and binomial distributions, [numpy.random.binamial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html)