# How to get exact probability of a binary function inpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, probability

Let us consider the function :

[image].

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571472/how-to-calculate-probability-of-a-binary-function-in-python).

I have written the corresponding python code given below:

```
def f(w):
    from fractions import Fraction
    from random import shuffle
    import random
    x=Fraction(w).limit_denominator()
#   print x (0<x<1)
    d=x.denominator
    n=x.numerator
    L=[0]*n+[1]*(d-n)
#   print L
    random.shuffle(L)
#   print L
    rc=random.choice(L)
    return rc
count0=0
count1=1
for i in range(1000):
    if f(0.375)==0:
        count0=count0+1
    else:
        count1=count1+1
print 'pr(f(0.375)=0)=',count0*1.0/1000
print 'pr(f(0.625)=1)=',count1*1.0/1000
```

Some outputs :
  1st output :

```
pr(f(0.375)=0)= 0.364
pr(f(0.625)=1)= 0.637
```

2nd output:

```
pr(f(0.375)=0)= 0.352
pr(f(0.625)=1)= 0.649
```

3rd output:

```
pr(f(0.375)=0)= 0.388
pr(f(0.625)=1)= 0.613
```

It does not dives the exact output. I need the exact probability value.   Here the output should be

```
pr(f(0.375)=0)= 0.375
pr(f(0.625)=1)= 0.625
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Are you in the same class as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44571472/744178)?

Comment: This question imported from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571472/how-to-calculate-probability-of-a-binary-function-in-python @jwodder

Comment: I don't understand the question, how a random process can get an "exact" result ?

Comment: Is there any alternative way to do this? @polku

Comment: If you want that exact output, `return w` from `f`

Comment: @polku the value of a random variable is, obviously, random; but the value of the probability of it getting a certain value is not random

Comment: My probability skills may be rusty, but if you consider n runs of finite sizes, the observed value at each run is indeed random. If the problem is that OP is surprised that a number as low as 1000 don't give him exactly 0.375 then it's not really a programming problem, any probability book could explain that. If my coin makes 7 heads and 3 tails, I'm not necessarily a cheater.